# py2exe ImportError

Tags: python, py2exe, importerror

I read the py2exe tutorial and successfully convert my python code to a running exectuable.

But when i tried to run it on another computer that dont have python installed , i get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program_Files\Pyton2_7_2\lib\site-packages\py2exe\boot_common.py", line 92, in 
>   ImportError: No module named linecache
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "auto_create_workspace.py", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named subprocess

On my computer , even if I uninstalled python , it still works.

**UPDATE**
I tried to copy the `dist` folder to another drive on my computer and it still working.
When I copy it to network drive and run from there , I get the same error as above.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Is there a subprocess.pyc or .pyo inside library.zip?

Comment: @janne Karila, subprocess.pyc exsit in library.zip.
otherwise it will not work on my computer also ,without python installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont know what is the problem in py2exe, so I tried pyinstaller instead and its works